# OSX Photos.app - How to programmatically set the Photos System Library

Tags: xcode, macos

So I'm trying to write a basic app that loads Photos.app libraries.

Seemingly in order to do this you need to be able to manipulate the current 'Photos System Library', as this is what is loaded with the MediaLibrary.

Wondering if anyone can highlight for me how you might go about this?

Cheers!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MediaLibraryLoader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017375 ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reference link, however, all this tells you how to do is specify a load type of photo library which loads the Photos System Library by default.  In light of this, in order to load different libraries the only way I can tell you might do this with this framework is to change the Photos System Library. Thanks again.